# The Xampp website cant be reatched by other computers in the network

Tags: php, html, networking, xampp

I m trying to make a website for a Smarthome project but I don't get other devices on the network to connect to the website, it just doesn't load.
I tried to reinstall Xampp but it didn't change anything, I also tried to reset all of the router settings, but again it didn't change anything.

Does someone have an idea of what may be off or what I could change to get it working?

Right now I m only running the default dashboard website with apache so it's not an error on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Start Apache and Mysql in Xampp then check the device IP address (win + x then type ipconfig) for windows then enter the IP address on another device connected to the same network. This should work. Also, confirm the port number Apache is running on.

Comment: I m already using the IP address so it didn't change anything, but the ports are the standard ports: 80, 443.